# SQL Server 2008 R2 query error: Incorrect syntax near ':'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with a certain query given to me and I don't know how to solve that problem.. here is the query..

```
  SELECT dcm.code DCM_No, 
         dcm.datetime_created DCM_Date,  
         lne.seq_number,
         par.code,
         par.description particular,
         ft.description fee_type,
     lne.amount, 
         case when lne.drcr =1 then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end DrCr,  

         case when isnull(dcm.is_sd,'N') = 'Y' then 'Salary Deduction' else null end is_sd,   
         org.description Company,
         org.postal_address company_addr,
         'S.Y. ' + substring(sy.school_year,1,4)+'-'+substring(sy.school_year,5,4) +' '+sem.description SY,
         entity_a.code + ' - ' + coalesce(entity_a.stud_lname,'') +', '+coalesce(entity_a.stud_fname,'') +' '+coalesce(entity_a.stud_mname,'') Student,

     case when   isnull(dm.description2,'') = '' then 
              crs.course_short_name + '-'+convert(char(1),entity_a.stud_grade)
        else    crs2.course_short_name + '-'+convert(char(1),reg.stud_grade) end as Course,
         isnull(dm.description2,'Not Enrolled')

    FROM  es.lib_rgn_students entity_a
        left join  ars.ars_dcm dcm on dcm.entity_id = entity_a.id
         LEFT JOIN afs.entity entity_b ON dcm.prepared_by_id = entity_b.id 
         LEFT JOIN ua.user_account ON dcm.prepared_by_id = ua.user_account.id
         left join ars.ars_dcm_line lne on lne.ars_dcm_id = dcm.id
         left join es.lib_fin_fees_master par on par.id = lne.ars_particular_id
         left join es.lib_fin_feetype ft on ft.code = lne.fee_code
        left join es.stp_sysem sy on sy.id = dcm.period_id
         inner join es.stp_semesterms sem on sem.code = sy.semester and sem.trimester = 0
         inner join afs.organization org on org.id = sy.company_id
         inner join es.lib_crs crs on crs.id = entity_a.course_id
         left join es.trn_rgn_reg_hdr reg on reg.period = sy.id and reg.stud_id = :as_studid
         left join document_status_map dm on dm.code = reg.document_status
         left join es.lib_crs crs2 on crs2.id = reg.course_id

   WHERE 
         (dcm.entity_id = :as_studid ) AND  
         ( dcm.period_id = :as_period ) AND  
         ( dcm.document_status_code not in(2,3) )
```

and I have this error:

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.

pls help i am not good with this :(

thanks!

Comment: Run it in management studio. Double click on the error message. It shows you `reg.stud_id = :as_studid` is the problem. If you are trying to use parameters these have a `@` prefix in TSQL.

Comment: i dont know what to do with this problem :( i seem to have the error regarding ":" .. what should i do? >_<

Comment: How are we supposed to know based on what you have told us? Is it the name of a column? If so delimit it as per Ross's answer. Is it supposed to be a parameter? If so declare it as a TSQL parameter with the `@` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:as_studid` and `:as_period` things are most likely parameters of this query as used by some client software. Before the query is actually executed, the `:name` bits are replaced (typically by some middle-tier software) with something like `@P1` or, maybe, `@as_studid`, so the server never sees the colons there (and never complains).

If you are not a client software developer and have simply been assigned the task of doing something with the query, then you need to apply the above mentioned transformations manually. I'd suggest you declared variables `@as_studid` and `@as_period` and use them instead of `:as_studid` and `:as_period` respectively. Also you'd probably need to assign them some values, so you could see some results when running the query. Here's an example of how the modified script might look like:

```
DECLARE
  @as_studid int,
  @as_period int;  /* those are just my guesses, the actual types
                      might need to be something other than int */

SET @as_studid = 10;
SET @as_period = 20; /* again, those are arbitrary values off the top
                        of my head but you might have to discover some
                        real ones before going on */

SELECT dcm.code DCM_No, 
       dcm.datetime_created DCM_Date,  
       lne.seq_number,
       par.code,
       par.description particular,
       ft.description fee_type,
   lne.amount, 
       case when lne.drcr =1 then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end DrCr,  

       case when isnull(dcm.is_sd,'N') = 'Y' then 'Salary Deduction' else null end is_sd,   
       org.description Company,
       org.postal_address company_addr,
       'S.Y. ' + substring(sy.school_year,1,4)+'-'+substring(sy.school_year,5,4) +' '+sem.description SY,
       entity_a.code + ' - ' + coalesce(entity_a.stud_lname,'') +', '+coalesce(entity_a.stud_fname,'') +' '+coalesce(entity_a.stud_mname,'') Student,

   case when   isnull(dm.description2,'') = '' then 
            crs.course_short_name + '-'+convert(char(1),entity_a.stud_grade)
      else    crs2.course_short_name + '-'+convert(char(1),reg.stud_grade) end as Course,
       isnull(dm.description2,'Not Enrolled')

  FROM  es.lib_rgn_students entity_a
      left join  ars.ars_dcm dcm on dcm.entity_id = entity_a.id
       LEFT JOIN afs.entity entity_b ON dcm.prepared_by_id = entity_b.id 
       LEFT JOIN ua.user_account ON dcm.prepared_by_id = ua.user_account.id
       left join ars.ars_dcm_line lne on lne.ars_dcm_id = dcm.id
       left join es.lib_fin_fees_master par on par.id = lne.ars_particular_id
       left join es.lib_fin_feetype ft on ft.code = lne.fee_code
      left join es.stp_sysem sy on sy.id = dcm.period_id
       inner join es.stp_semesterms sem on sem.code = sy.semester and sem.trimester = 0
       inner join afs.organization org on org.id = sy.company_id
       inner join es.lib_crs crs on crs.id = entity_a.course_id
       left join es.trn_rgn_reg_hdr reg on reg.period = sy.id and reg.stud_id = :as_studid
       left join document_status_map dm on dm.code = reg.document_status
       left join es.lib_crs crs2 on crs2.id = reg.course_id

 WHERE 
       (dcm.entity_id = @as_studid ) AND   -- the vars declared above are used
       ( dcm.period_id = @as_period ) AND  -- here instead of the ':'-bits
       ( dcm.document_status_code not in(2,3) )
```

Alternatively you could do without variables, just replace `:as_studid` and `:as_period` with some (real) values. But that way you'd have to remember what exactly was parametrised in the original query, for, in any event, if your task was to modify the query itself, you might have to submit it back with the `:`-names, just like you received it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! iv'e been looking answers about this for about 2 days now.. i really don't know what to do with the error i have occurred.. i don't have much idea about this.. i was just assigned to do this.. you save my life thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

If you column really is called :as_studid then surround it with square brackets. e.g.:-

```
   WHERE 
         (dcm.entity_id = [:as_studid] ) AND  
         ( dcm.period_id = [:as_period] ) AND  
         ( dcm.document_status_code not in(2,3) )
```

That should fix the issue